# Getting Paw to prompt for a value

Tags: paw-app

How can I get Paw to prompt me to provide a value? E.g. for a `name` field in a JSON request body such as the following:

```
{
    "name": [prompt me when I send the request]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @BillMote Nope. :|